emacs can't start libreoffice process, stuck by oosplash?
When attempting to open a .ods file externally, either with ! in a dired buffer or with embark-open-externally, no libreoffice window opens but the processes oosplash and soffice.bin are running.

As a first check, can you open the file from a terminal? If not maybe the problem is with your LibreOffice installation.

Yes, i can open the file from the terminal

What OS are you using? I have the same two processes running on Linux (Fedora 40), but no problem with the file.

I'm using Ubuntu 24.04

According to this discussion, using setsid -w xdg-open should fix this problem. It does work, except when using an emacsclient whose daemon is run from a systemd service.
